# Simplify multiple recurring case expression within "select" and "where"

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query:

```
SELECT  CASE
   WHEN @from < item.UpdatedOnCurr AND item.UpdatedOnCurr <= @till AND @till < item.UpdatedOnNext
       THEN item.Id
   ELSE '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
        END AS Id,
        CASE
            WHEN @from < item.UpdatedOnCurr AND item.UpdatedOnCurr <= @till AND @till < item.UpdatedOnNext
            THEN item.PreviousId
            ELSE item.Id
        END AS PreviousId,
        item.UUID,
        CASE
            WHEN @from < item.UpdatedOnCurr AND item.UpdatedOnCurr <= @till AND @till < item.UpdatedOnNext
            THEN item.Json
            ELSE NULL
        END AS Json,
        item.TableName,
        item.PermissionId,
        item.UpdatedOnCurr

FROM Computed item
WHERE item.Json IS NOT NULL AND (
        (@from < item.UpdatedOnCurr AND item.UpdatedOnCurr <= @till AND @till < item.UpdatedOnNext)
    OR (item.UpdatedOnCurr <= @from AND @from < item.UpdatedOnNext AND item.UpdatedOnNext <= @till)
);
```

And I would like to simplify it, i.e. all those multiple `CASE` expressions are cutting my eyeballs out, so I'd like to reuse `@from < item.UpdatedOnCurr AND item.UpdatedOnCurr <= @till AND @till < item.UpdatedOnNext` check so that it won't execute multiple times per each selected row...

So how do you achieve that?

Comment: put it into cte, calc case predicate once and filter within cte, use simple cases in outer query

Comment: You could write a function and just call that

Comment: That's case expressions! (Not case statements...)

Comment: Fixed naming, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With *APPLY* you can clean-up some of those repeating logic. The CASE is still there.. but i find it more readable.

```
SELECT  CASE m.m
            WHEN 1
            THEN item.Id
            ELSE '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
        END AS Id,
        CASE m.m
            WHEN 1
            THEN item.PreviousId
            ELSE item.Id
        END AS PreviousId,
        item.UUID,
        CASE m.m
            WHEN 1
            THEN item.Json
            ELSE NULL
        END AS Json,
        item.TableName,
        item.PermissionId,
        item.UpdatedOnCurr

FROM Computed item
CROSS APPLY (
    select
        CASE
            WHEN @from < item.UpdatedOnCurr AND item.UpdatedOnCurr <= @till AND @till < item.UpdatedOnNext
            THEN 1
            ELSE 0 
        END m
) m
WHERE item.Json IS NOT NULL AND (
        (@from < item.UpdatedOnCurr AND item.UpdatedOnCurr <= @till AND @till < item.UpdatedOnNext)
    OR (item.UpdatedOnCurr <= @from AND @from < item.UpdatedOnNext AND item.UpdatedOnNext <= @till)
);
```